javascript reduce(),keys(), filter() method
While solving a problem to find missing numbers from an array.


let arr = [15,3,5,6,7,2,1,8,12];

let findMissing = (arr)=>{
    let res = arr.reduce((acc,n)=>{
        acc[n]=1;
        return acc;
    },[])
    
    return [...res.keys()].filter((i)=>{
        if(res[i]!==1) return i
    })
}

console.log(findMissing(arr));



output:[4, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14]
Issue is why output does not have zero in it: [0,4, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14]

Can you clarify why you expect the output to be different?  When using a debugger, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  (You may need to separate some of your combined operations for more granularity in your debugging.)  What were the inputs to that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

because you return i in the filter method (you return 0).
i === 0 && 0 == false it is filtered out because when returning a falsy value for a filter function it will strip it.
if you return true like in my example it works.


let arr = [15,3,5,6,7,2,1,8,12];

let findMissing = (arr)=>{
    let res = arr.reduce((acc,n)=>{
        acc[n]=1;
        return acc;
    },[])
    
    return [...res.keys()].filter((i)=>{
        return res[i] !== 1
    })
}

console.log(findMissing(arr));




Alternatively, findMissing() can be written as a one-liner, using .reduce() and .includes():


let arr = [15,3,5,6,7,2,1,8,12];

let findMissing=arr=>
  Array(Math.max(...arr)+1).fill(0)
  .reduce((a,_,i)=>(!arr.includes(i)&&a.push(i),a),[]);

console.log(findMissing(arr));



However, the performance could be improved by creating a Set s from arr with s=new Set(arr) and then using !s.has(i) instead of !arr.includes(i) inside the reduce() callback function.
When sort()ing the array initially we can do the job without using .includes() or .has():


let arr = [15,3,5,6,7,2,1,8,12];

let findMissing=arr=>{ let i=0;
  return [...arr].sort((a,b)=>a-b)
  .reduce((a,v)=>{
    while(i<v) a.push(i++);
    ++i;
    return a},[]);
}

console.log(findMissing(arr));



